# Gradio - Pytorch MNIST Digit Recognizer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, mnist, gradio

I watched the following video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx9iyQZhSwI where it was shown that it is possible to use Gradio and the learned model of MNIST dataset in Tensorflow. I have read and written that it is possible to use Pytorch in Gradio, but I have problems with its implementation. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
My Pytorch code of cnn

```
import torch.nn as nn
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1,              
                out_channels=16,            
                kernel_size=5,              
                stride=1,                   
                padding=2,                  
            ),                              
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),    
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),     
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),                
        )
        # fully connected layer, output 10 classes
        self.out = nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, 10)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        # flatten the output of conv2 to (batch_size, 32 * 7 * 7)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)       
        output = self.out(x)
        return output, x    # return x for visualization
```

By watching I find that  I need to change function that Gradio use

```
def predict_image(img):
  img_3d=img.reshape(-1,28,28)
  im_resize=img_3d/255.0
  prediction=CNN(im_resize)
  pred=np.argmax(prediction)
  return pred
```

Comment: Could you please describe more specifically?

Comment: Gradio's idea, after training the neural network on the MNIST dataset, is to draw a digit yourself and see how the network works. In the example on YouTube, that network was learned through Tensorflow, and I wonder if there is a way to do it through Pytorch.

Comment: can you upload the full version of your code? and you said you had problems with implementation, can you clarify what are those problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry if I got your question wrong, but from what I understand you are getting an error when trying to predict the digit using your function predict image.

So here are two possible hints. Maybe you have implemented them already, but I don't know because of the very small code snippet.

First of all. Have you set your model into evaluation mode using

```
CNN.eval()
```

Do after you finished training your model and want to evaluate inputs without training the model.

Second of all, maybe you need to add a fourth dimension to your input tensor "im_resize". Normally your model expects a dimension for the number of channels, the batch size, the height and the width of your input.
In addition I can not tell if your input is a of the datatype torch.tensor . If not transform your array into a tensor first.

You can add a batch dimension to your input tensor by using

```
im_resize = im_resize.unsqueeze(0)
```

I hope that I understand your question correctly and was able to help you.